# Internet Explorer Compatibility Issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility

I recently opened a [webiste](http://xn--9dbbt.net/). It's a Shoppica theme running on an `open cart CMS`. It works fine on all browsers except `Internet Explorer` (although it works on one version of internet explorer apparently as well.) I messed for hours with the css changing stuff.I even tried adding Reset css but to no avail. 
Any ideas about what should I do ?

Comment: Any specific issue? If yes than post it here else your question will be closed soon

Comment: You need to be specific about your problems.. don't just say "go to this site and see the problem", since the problem is likely not obvious to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in your header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: IT WORKED THANKS A LOT!!!!!
You can't believe how grateful I am for your help!

Comment: @user1927797: ur welcome :)